# aws s3 createBucket function always returns S3 BucketAlreadyExists

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using aws S3 php api to create bucket as shown below, but it returns this error message whatever I try

> The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is
> shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and
> try again.

**when I try to create bucket on aws console which I've tried before on api, it works on aws console**

here is my sample code

```
function createBucket($s3Client, $bucketName)
    {
        try {
            $result = $s3Client->createBucket([
                'Bucket' => $bucketName,
            ]);
            return 'The bucket\'s location is: ' .
                $result['Location'] . '. ' .
                'The bucket\'s effective URI is: ' . 
                $result['@metadata']['effectiveUri'];
        } catch (AwsException $e) {
            return 'Error: ' . $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
        }
    }
    
    function createTheBucket($name)
    {
        define('AWS_KEY', 'AWS_KEY');
        define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', 'AWS_SECRET_KEY');
        define('REGION', 'eu-west-1');



        // Establish connection with DreamObjects with an S3 client.
        $s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version'     => '2006-03-01',
            'region'      => REGION,
                'credentials' => [
                'key'      => AWS_KEY,
                'secret'   => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
            ]
        ]);
        

        echo createBucket($s3Client, $name);
    }
```

Comment: "The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system." kind of undersells it, the bucket namespace is shared by _everyone on the planet_. The name you're using must be globally unique in the most literal sense.

Comment: I know the bucket name is must be unique, so I tried Things you wouldn't even think of. Besides I said when I try to create bucket on aws console which I've tried before on api, it works on aws console

Comment: Is there any more code that you haven't shown us? Any chance that you are accidentally calling `createBucket(...)` twice with the same parameters, so the 2nd invocation fails with BucketAlreadyExists?

Answer (score 2):

The S3 bucket you are trying to create has already been created in the AWS namespace.

Its important to understand that S3 buckets have a unique name amongst the entire AWS global namespace.

Ensure your bucket name does not collide with anyone else's or one of your own.

> An Amazon S3 bucket name is globally unique, and the namespace is shared by all AWS accounts. This means that after a bucket is created, the name of that bucket cannot be used by another AWS account in any AWS Region until the bucket is deleted. You should not depend on specific bucket naming conventions for availability or security verification purposes.

If the S3 bucket name is free then its possible that either a hard coded value has overridden the `$bucketName` variable or that code logic (such as looping or formatting parameters) is trying to recreate a bucket that has already existed.

The best way to discover to validate the variable `$bucketName` value throughout your scrip execution.

Comment: I know, but if you read carefully I said "when I try to create bucket on aws console which I've tried before on api, it works on aws console"

Comment: Have you performed a `var_dump($bucketName);` just before you attempt the createBucket function to validate what is being passed into it?